# is it possible to denote some set of argparse's arguments without using subparsers?

Tags: python, argparse

I have an `argparser`, with two subsets of arguments, inputs and parameters. My command looks something like

```
program -input1 <input1> -input2 <input2> -p1 <param1> -p2 <param2>
```

I'd love to

```
args = parser.parse_args()
params = vars(args.params)
```

instead of

```
params = {"p1": args.p1, "p2": args.p2, etc...}
```

Is there an elegant way to do something like:

```
parser.add_argument("-p1", dest='p1', part_of=params)
```

[Subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) don't seem like they're made for this. Or are they?

Argparse has [argument groups](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argument-groups), but they seem like they're just for the help text.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.  Do you mean that `-p1` and `-p2` can only occur with/as substructures/"suboptions" of `-input2`?

Comment: Argument groups are mostly useful for mutually exclusive options. What is the nature of your groups? E.g. could you just prefix `dest` to help group parameters?

Comment: how do you go about prefixing dest? @9000

Comment: @jwodder, no, all the args are independent and can be specified in any combination. But since some of the args are "parameters" I'd like to be able to have them as a group just by calling `params = vars(args.params)`

Comment: @AlexLenail: So you just want the option values to be stored on a subobject of `args`?  I don't think `argparse` supports that.

Comment: @jwodder That's right

Comment: @AlexLenail: my idea was  `parser.add_argument('-p1', ... dest='output_p1')`, etc. Then you could group parsing results yourself by `.strartswith('output_')`, cutting off prefixes if you want.

Comment: @9000 not a bad idea... I feel like argument groups should just be available in the namespace though...

Comment: Argument Groups control the help lines; Mutually exclusive groups control tests during parsing and usage line. Do not confuse them.  There's no built-in grouping mechanism for the `namespace`, except that provided by `nargs` and `append`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a variation on the - how do I accept arbitrary 'key=value' pairs?  It's been asked in various ways over the years, with various answers.

In a recent one:

[Parsing "python foo.py -DVAR1=9 -DVAR2=Off" with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243996/parsing-python-foo-py-dvar1-9-dvar2-off-with-argparse)

my solution was to split `-DVAR1=9` into `('VAR1',9)` and append that to the `D` attribute.  That uses a custom `type`.

[Using variable arg names with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330373/using-variable-arg-names-with-argparse) - this processes the `sys.argv` before passing it to the parser.

[python argparse store --foo=bar as args.key='foo', args.value='bar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018928/python-argparse-store-foo-bar-as-args-key-foo-args-value-bar)

suggests a custom `Action` class.

I think we've also suggested a custom `Namespace` class.

The builtin mechanisms for grouping values are `nargs` and `append` action.  Together you can get attributes which are lists of lists.

JSON strings can also be used to input complex data structures.

---

```
class MyAction(argparse._StoreAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print('storing', option_string)
        arg = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        if arg is None:
            arg = {}
        arg[option_string] = values
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, arg)

In [135]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [136]: p.add_argument('--p1',action=MyAction,dest='p');
In [137]: p.add_argument('--p2',action=MyAction,dest='p');
In [138]: p.parse_args('--p1 one --p2 two'.split())
storing --p1
storing --p2
Out[138]: Namespace(p={'--p2': 'two', '--p1': 'one'})
In [139]: _.p
Out[139]: {'--p1': 'one', '--p2': 'two'}
```

Obviously this could be refined in various ways - trimming the keys to 'p1' or even '1', saving to a list, or nested Namespace or other custom structure, etc.

This approach still requires that you define an `add_argument` for each '--pn` variation.

An alternative is keep `argparse` simple, producing a namespace like:

```
In [141]: argparse.Namespace(p1='one', p2='two', input1=1, input2=3)
Out[141]: Namespace(input1=1, input2=3, p1='one', p2='two')
```

and then do your own grouping afterwards.

```
In [142]: args=argparse.Namespace(p1='one', p2='two', input1=1, input2=3)
In [143]: {key:getattr(args,key) for key in ['p1','p2']}
Out[143]: {'p1': 'one', 'p2': 'two'}
```

Comment: can you do better? Re-reading my question -- which has become relevant again -- I feel like this functionality should be provided by python. I don't know much about the governance of python, but I'd love to contribute this. In my mind, this would build off the [argument groups](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argument-groups) which is already there, but only used for the help text...

Comment: You are welcomed to search for `argparse` issues on `http://bugs.python.org/`.  Study some of those, both open and closed ones, to see what's involved in making a change.  There are two challenges 1) making the case that this is an urgent and general problem, and 2) writing a complete patch (with tests and documentation).